# jQuery code that expands/collapses divs individually from a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a HTML page that displays an album track list. It should allow users to click a drop down and see the lyrics to a specific track. I have a jquery function that drops down the lyrics however...
- it drops down all lyrics not just selected track
- you can open all the tabs together, when a tab is clicked it should close the previously opened tab

My current Code for reference:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

        $(".lyrics").hide();
        $(".dropdownheader").show();

    $('.dropdownheader').click(function()
    {
        $(".lyrics").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

HTML:`

```
                <li> 
                    <p class="dropdownheader">Song 1 </p>
                    <p class="lyrics">
                        Sing Song 
                    </p>
                    <audio controls height="100" width="100">
                        <source src="a.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
                        <embed height="50" width="100" src="horse.mp3"></embed>
                    </audio>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` to slide down the clicked lyrics:

```
$('.dropdownheader').click(function()
{
    $(".lyrics").slideUp(); <-- Hide any other lyrics that are showing
    $(this).next(".lyrics").slideDown(); <-- Slide down clicked lyrics.
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/earNm/

Comment: Great, but is there anyway to:
A. prevent the header from hiding then showing when it is click when already showing the content? B. Anyway to stop the animation from being "jagged" at the end of it. it appears to slide then suddenly clip into place.